# converting oracle Date field Object to java Date

Tags: java, oracle, date, casting

I have a Date field in Oracle DB.

Date field1

Now  there is a existing DAO that fetches this field1 in form of Object

```
Object field1
```

Now I need to typeCast it to java Date

```
But if i do like following i get error:
Date dt = (Date) object;  //object holds date object
DateTime jdt = new DateTime(dt) ; //convert it to jodaDate
```

Error : `cannot cast Long to Date.`

How to convert it to javaDate and than Joda DateTime

Comment: Object doesn't hold a `Date` object, it holds a `Long`. How are you fetching that value?

Comment: There is a DAO which is already fetching it in form of object

Comment: Yes, but the underlying field in the database is of type `date`?

Comment: If you are using JDBC, you may have to tell your DAO that your column is a DATE. It may use methods like getLong, getString, getDate on the ResultSet object based on the type you told it to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the datatype `DATE` in the Oracle DB with the Java type `Date`. The error `cannot cast Long to Date` states that the object you are holding is of the Java type `Long`, which is why the cast to the Java `Date` type fails. The Long represents the number of seconds or miliseconds since 01/01/1970, depending on yor DOA layer (see it's documentation), since the DATE precision in Oracle only goes down to seconds. To receive a date, use `new Date((long) object)` or `new Date(1000 * (long) object)` respectively.

You also can use those number of milliseconds to generate a `DateTime` directly without using the Java `Date` class at all.

Answer (score 0):

The object that is fetched is a Long type, as evident from the error message. Now, you can simple contruct a *java.util.Date* object from a Long object as below:

```
Date dt = new Date((Long)object)
```